# how to rotate all the tables created by sidewaytables to the same direction

Tags: tables, rotating, sidewaystable

I have four tables created in `sidewaystable`, but it looks like they are randomly rotated meaning that while one table head is on the left, the other table head looks to the right. I tried `adjustbox`, `rotating`, and `figuresleft` package, but none of them change the direction of the tables. Is there a way that when I create a  `sidewaystable`, they all rotate in the same direction?

I am using `informs3` document class. Here is a small example.

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{1}{l}}
     \toprule
     Column \\
    \midrule
     800      \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{1}{l}}
     \toprule
     Column \\
    \midrule
       800      \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

this is how they look in the document. As you can see, the tables are looking at the different directions.

[image]

Comment: Either don't use a twoside document class, or use [figureright] or [figureleft] in the rotating package options (see page 2 of the manual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `informs3.cls` requires tables to be input in a different way than standard document classes do, you can not use `sidewaystable` from the `rotating` package in combination with said document class. Instead,  `informs3.cls` offers their own alternative `rotate` environment.

> **9.3. Rotated Figures and Tables** In cases where a figure, or more often a table, is so large that it cannot reasonably fit in the
>   portrait position, landscape setting is also available. The whole
>   environment (figure or table) should be surrounded by
>
> ```
> \begin{rotate}
> <table or figure>
> \end{rotate}
> ```
>
> Before resorting to this extreme measure, please try smaller type size
>   for the table body or even some reworking/restructuring to make it
>   fit.

A MWE would be the following code:

```
\documentclass[ijoc]{informs3}
\begin{document}

\begin{rotate}
\begin{table}
\TABLE
{Text of the Table Caption.\label{tab2}}
{\begin{tabular}{ll}
entries or the table & entries or the table
\end{tabular}}
{Text of the notes.}
\end{table}
\end{rotate}

\begin{rotate}
\begin{table}
\TABLE
{Text of the Table Caption.\label{tab2}}
{\begin{tabular}{ll}
entries or the table & entries or the table
\end{tabular}}
{Text of the notes.}
\end{table}
\end{rotate}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, both tables are automatically rotated in the same direction.

Comment: I am using ```informs3``` class and ```figuresleft``` did not work. The tables stay the same.

Comment: Where did you get `inform3.cls` from?

Comment: You can find the document class at https://pubsonline.informs.org/authorportal/latex-style-files

Comment: I can only find `informs3.cls` there (from the link Information Systems Research Style Files) Is this the file that you refer to? Please also include this information into the question itself and please also prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe without guessing your code.

Comment: Could you download the Informs Journal on Computing sample? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ball_jan: I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: When I use rotate, it does not rotate the table. Is there an extra command that I should place?

Comment: Did you use the exact same code from my answer or did you incorporate the rotate environment into your original document?